# Why does a descendant selector override a class selector?

Tags: css

I have classes like this:

```
.tableGeneric tr td
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.tdValignTop
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

When I apply these classes, I expect that a `td` with class `.tdValignTop` would be vertically-aligned to the top, even when `.tableGeneric` tries to align it to the middle. However, it would seem that I am wrong: the table cell would use `.tableGeneric`'s styles instead of `.tdValignTop`'s styles.

[Here's a fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/6yP5M/6/).

So... **why**? Isn't a specific class style/selector supposed to override base/parent styles? Is there some kind of logic or reasoning behind this behavior? I assume the behavior is intentional, but I cannot find any documentation on it.

Comment: For one, you misspelled vertical. `verticle-align`. Second, check our CSS specificity.

Comment: @j08691 Oh. Oops. Fixed that, thanks. The "problem" is still present though.

Comment: Have you checked into CSS specificity?

Comment: As @j08691 points out, it's a [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue.. Also, remove the line breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/8p6k4/

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yeah, the line breaks were stupid. I updated the fiddle without the line breaks. As for specificity, I didn't know that was what I should search for. Thanks, I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you think of as “specific” is not more specific in the CSS sense, and it is CSS specificity that matters when applying CSS. The [CSS specificity rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) define specificity on terms of the syntactic structure of a selector. In this case, the first selector has one class name and two element names, so it is more specific than the other, which only contains a class name.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! I always thought CSS styles are applied based on the "lowest-level element". I never knew about CSS specificity, hence why I was confused, and failed to search for relevant results (until people mentioned it in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the first style rule you defined is more specific than the second, thus it will override.

If you do this it will work as you expect:

```
.tableGeneric tr td
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.tableGeneric tr td.tdValignTop
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6yP5M/7/).

Comment: I get that it's more specific, but my question is *why* it would be more specific than the second style rule, applied directly to the element.